# new locationclient(this,this,this) compile error

Tags: android

I am trying to update an old tutorial with the new google location services.  I am using the code directly from google tutorial, yet the line   mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this); returns an error The constructor LocationClient(RunFragment, RunFragment, RunFragment) is undefined

The only difference between my code and the tutorial is that I am running it in onCreateView in a fragment instead of from an Activity.  Any suggestions how I can correct this?  Thanks.

```
public class RunFragment extends Fragment implements
```

LocationListener,
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private Button mStartButton, mStopButton;
private TextView mStartedTextView, mLatitudeTextView, 
    mLongitudeTextView, mAltitudeTextView, mDurationTextView;


// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
private LocationClient mLocationClient;

// Handle to SharedPreferences for this app
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

// Handle to a SharedPreferences editor
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

/*
 * Note if updates have been turned on. Starts out as "false"; is set to "true" in the
 * method handleRequestSuccess of LocationUpdateReceiver.
 *
 */
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_run, container, false);

    mStartedTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.run_startedTextView);
    mLatitudeTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.run_latitudeTextView);
    mLongitudeTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.run_longitudeTextView);
    mAltitudeTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.run_altitudeTextView);
    mDurationTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.run_durationTextView);

    mStartButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.run_startButton);


    mStopButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.run_stopButton);

    // Create a new global location parameters object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    /*
     * Set the update interval
     */
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
    mUpdatesRequested = false;

    // Open Shared Preferences

    mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Get an editor
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);



    //updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument has to be the context of an Activity.

Declare in your MainActivity:

```
public static Context c;
```

And in the onCreate method of the MainActivity:

```
c = this;
```

Now you can call your method like this:

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(MainActivity.c, this, this);
```

Note: MainActivity is the Activity that has inflated your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get the activity and pass to the LocationClient, not the Fragment

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getActivity(),this,this);
```