# Creating a LocationClient outside of an onCreate()?

Tags: android, google-play-services

So I basically have the same problem seen here [new locationclient(this,this,this) compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638952/new-locationclientthis-this-this-compile-error)
in that I have a class outside of my MainActivity that I want to use for location tracking which I need to pass a context into. The class is run in the background from a broadcast receiver when the MainActivity isnt running, so I can't just call MainActivity.context like the solution in the other post.

I tried passing a context in like I normally would here:

```
public void createLoc(Context context) {
    mLocClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
}
```

but got a similar error of LocationClient(Context, MonitorLocation, MonitorLocation) is undefined.

If anybody could help me get this functioning it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the users location it might be null because that is an asynchronous call.  I would suggest putting this code in a service if it is long running..